# WCF to MVC Web API for WebInvoke Attribute (BodyStyle = WrappedRequest)

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to recreate a WCF Web Service into MVC Web API that has the following attribute on a Web Method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```

VB:

```
<WebInvoke(Method = "*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)> _
```

**What is the MVC Web API way of creating a Wrapped Request?**

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue and couldn't find any solution, however, the below is my work-around for.

Creating WrappedResponse as a name/value structure.

```
public class WrappedResponse<T>
    {
        public List<T> SampleCollection { get; set; }
        public static WrappedResponse<T> GetResult(List<T> list)
        {
            var result = new WrappedResponse<T>();
            result.SampleCollection = list;
            return result;
        }       
    }
```

Returning WrappedResponse instance.

```
[Route("Products")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            using (var context = new AdventureWorks2012Entities())
            {
                List<Product> productsList = context.Products.Take(10).ToList();
                var result = WrappedResponse<Product>.GetResult(productsList);
                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
```